# Sum input integers

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I want to run a file that adds up the values in the command line.
So, *node myscript 1 5 10* returns 16.

However, it seems that in my code, *sum* changes into an array variable - somehow.
I'd like to know why this happens, and what the correct formulation should be.

```
var array = process.argv;
var count = array.length - 1;
var i = 2;
var sum = 0;

console.log("There are " + (count - 1) + " individual numbers.");

while (i <= count) {
    sum += array[i];    
    i++;
}

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Could be wrong but the math seems off on your _"There are " + (count - 1) + " individual numbers."_ statement. `array.length` will give you the number of individual numbers. `array.length - 1` (or count) will give you the last value's `index` in the array. `array.length - 2` (which is the same as `count - 1` will give you the next to last value's index in the array, not the total number of individual numbers.

Comment: [Because that's how Node.js works.](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv)

Comment: @undefined: OP is aware `array` is an array, but is confused about what `sum` is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input variables are given as Strings and not Numbers, so in order to sum them up, you need to convert them to numbers:

```
sum += +array[i];

// or

sum += parseInt( array[i], 10 );
```

In your current code, you concatenate the Strings (and `sum`'s initial value gets converted to a String as well).

Comment: ...otherwise you are just concatenating strings ;)

Comment: @RocketHazmat Right :-) Added.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `array` is an array of strings, not numbers. This means that `0` is being turned into a string `"0"` and then concatenated with other string variables.

You could turn `array` into an array of `Number`s like this:

```
array = argv.slice(1).map(Number)
```

Note that I have removed the first entry, the name of the program, using `slice`.

You can now loop through `array` starting from element `0` and your code will work as expected.

Working example (making use of the esoteric [`-->` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator) ;)

```
var array = argv.slice(1).map(Number);
var count = array.length;
var sum = 0;

console.log("There are " + count + " individual numbers.");

while (count --> 0) sum += array[count];
console.log(sum);
```

---

#### update

Instead of using `map`, you may as well use `reduce`:

```
var array = argv.slice(1);
console.log("There are " + array.length + " individual numbers.");
var sum = array.reduce(function(prev, curr) { return prev + +curr }, 0);
console.log(sum);
```

`reduce` combines all of the values of `array` using the function provided. The unary `+` operator is used to convert the values in `array` to numbers. The second argument is the initial value of the sum.